# Including lots of jspf files in a jsp file causes high memory usage

Tags: jsp, glassfish, memory-management, jspinclude, jsp-fragments

We have a web page, running on a glassfish server. In our jsp file we have a lot of includes like the one below.

```
<jsp:directive.include file="johndoe/foobar.jspf"/>
```

These files are included according to the user choice. Our jsp file is basically like this:

```
<jsp:root version="2.1" xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core_rt"
xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core" 
xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
xmlns:jsp="http://java.sun.com/JSP/Page" 
xmlns:webuijsf="http://www.sun.com/webui/webuijsf">
//some unimportant codes here
<c:if test="${sessionScope.loadAvgTest}">
  //some unimportant codes here
  <f:subview id="reports15">
    <jsp:directive.include file="siforms/sysinfoform.jspf"/>
  </f:subview>
  //some unimportant codes here                                        
  <f:subview id="reports16">
    <jsp:directive.include file="siforms/sysinfoformscheduled.jspf"/>
  </f:subview>
   //some unimportant codes here
</c:if>
//some unimportant codes here
<c:if test="${sessionScope.bandwidthTest}">
  //some unimportant codes here
  <f:subview id="reports17">
    <jsp:directive.include file="mailforms/mailfilter.jspf"/>
  </f:subview>
  //some unimportant codes here
  <f:subview id="reports18">
    <jsp:directive.include file="mailforms/mailfilterscheduled.jspf"/>
  </f:subview>
//some unimportant codes here
</c:if>
....
```

There are approximately 80 if statements like this each one containing 2 inculdes. When I removed a lot of these if clauses and leaved only a few if and a few include memory usage was fine. But as I use more if clauses and more includes the memory usage grows. Any ideas how I can optimize the code or how I can make configuration changes to the servlets configuration to lower the memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `jsp:include` instead of `jsp:directive.include` solved the problem. 
As far as I have learned from my research `jsp:directive.include` (include directive) includes the file into the JSP page at compile time whereas `jsp:include` includes the output at runtime.

```
I have found that, include action (runtime include) runs a bit slower 
yet it is preferred generally because it save a lot of memory of the system.
```

([source](http://www.roseindia.net/help/java/i/includedirective-vs-includeaction.shtml))

Answer (score 0):

You're using JSF. At view creation time, if an `if` statement evaluates to true, the JSF controls on the page will be added to the component tree. For server-side state saving, these [UIComponent](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/UIComponent.html) instances and [their state](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/component/StateHolder.html#saveState%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext%29) will (by default) be persisted in the user's session. The more controls you add, the more memory you are going to consume. By default, a number of old views are persisted in the session.

You could try:

- Not building large object graphs
- Reducing the number of views in the session (see `com.sun.faces.numberOfViewsInSession` and `com.sun.faces.numberOfLogicalViews` or equivalent initialization parameters for your implementation)
- Using a JSF version with [partial state saving](http://andyschwartz.wordpress.com/2009/07/31/whats-new-in-jsf-2/#state-saving) if you are not already (this may involve upgrading Glassfish)
- Implementing a [StateManager](http://java.sun.com/javaee/6/docs/api/javax/faces/application/StateManager.html) to save your state out of RAM (e.g. to a database, but this leads to its own problems) or switching to client-side state saving with the default implementation (see `javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD` - this comes with security concerns and may alter application behaviour)